# How to build VS solution folder from powershell

Tags: .net, visual-studio, powershell, command-line, build-automation

From Visual Studio I can build several projects grouped by solution folder by right click -> Build.

[image: Solution folder build command]

Is there any command line / power shell alternative for that?

Comment: msbuild.exe is your friend, isn't it?

Answer (score 6):

In the screenshot above just do following:

```
 cd [directory with WindowsFormsApplication1.sln]
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
```

Powershell is just "console". For building sln or csproj you need to [msbuild.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393574.aspx) which is a tool for building .NET projects

If you want only to build one solution folder from sln it is not so easy because folders in Visual Studio are virtual and you need to parse sln file to find folders

**Update**

The following code will parse sln file and run msbuild for project which belongs to folder:

```
param([string]$slnPath=".\YourSLN.sln", [string]$VsFolderName="Your_folder")

$slnContent = Get-Content $slnPath 
$folderLine = $slnContent | ?{$_.Contains("2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8")} | ?{$_.Contains($VsFolderName)}

$guid = $folderLine.Split(", ")[-1].Replace('"',"")
#Write-host $guid

$csprojGuids = $slnContent | ?{$_.Contains("= "+$guid)}  | %{$_.Split("=")[-2].Trim()}

#Write-Host $csprojGuids 

for($i=0; $i -lt $csprojGuids.count; $i++){
    $toFind = $csprojGuids[$i]
    $def = $slnContent | ?{$_.Contains("Project")} | ?{$_.Contains($csprojGuids[$i])} | %{$_.Split(",")[-2].Trim().Replace('"','')}
    Write-Host "building" $def
    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe $def
}
```

Comment: there are several hundreds of projects in the solution, that's why I need to scope the build to one particular folder to speed up the process.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DTE to get paths of projects and then pass them to msbuild. Run this from Package Manager Console (presuming msbuild is in your %path%):

```
project|% dte|% solution|? projectname -eq NewFolder1|% projectitems|% object|% {msbuild $_.fullname}
```

Comment: that's exactly what I need, but is there any chance to run it outside of Visual Studio?

Comment: @VladimirSachek Take a look at [StudioShell](https://studioshell.codeplex.com), otherwise you can access DTE from outside of VS without any special extension. I have some C# code for it, so let me know in case StudioShell won't work.